# Iframe Url after initial page is navigated from

Tags: php, url, iframe, same-origin-policy

Hey i am wondering if their is a way to get the URL of the page showen in a iframe with php or javascript. i want it so that when i user clicks a link in the iframe so it isnt the initial iframed page then clicks another button that button it will get the new URL of page that is currently in the iframe. thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, Same-Origin-Policy will not permit this unless the new location is on the same hostname as the original location.